# How do I separate multiple values for "print render($content['field']);" with a comma?

Tags: nodes, theming

So in my node template, I am using the following code:

```
print render($content['field_taxonomy']);
```

Sometimes there is only one result printed, and sometimes there are multiple results printed. How can I separate each result by a comma, but only if there are multiple results printed?

Thank you!

Comment: put this in a loop so you will get result separately.

Comment: @NishantP how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

For example, I am fetching the texonomy vocabulary terms :

```
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('vid' => '12')); 
foreach ($terms as $temsaccess) {
$name[]=$temsaccess->name;
}

<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="<?php echo $term_name; ?>" Click="javascript:showProduct('<?php echo $term_name; ?>', this );"  data-filter="<?php echo $temsaccess; ?>">
<?php echo $temsaccess; ?>
</a>
```

Or refer to this [link](http://www.wdtutorials.com/2012/09/11/drupal-7-and-drupal-6-how-print-taxonomy-terms-templates#.VQZsbtLLfwk).